# Reading & Inserting events to calendar

Tags: android, android-calendar

I'm using the following code to insert an event (Programmatically, not by intent) to specific calendar (with it's ID)

```
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, cname);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, note);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, tz.getDisplayName());
        if (recurrence != null)
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, "FREQ=" + recurrence + ";");
        Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Insert works great, i'm saving the event id:
**uri.getLastPathSegment()**

but the issue is how to read this **specific event** from the **specific calendar** ?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the contentResolver to query CalendarContract.Events with a selection on the eventId

To fetch the calendarId it's something like this:

```
Uri calUri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, mAccountName)
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, mAccountType)
            .build();

getContentResolver().query(calUri, new String[]{CalendarContract.Calendars._ID}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Tried that, but it gives me event of other calendar, need to specify calendar id somehow

Comment: Well...it's very strange that you can insert to db but can't query and need to do some logic on calendars ... i'll mark this as an answer even if it's not helping me by much.

Answer (score 0):

you can put insert reminder and event in calender by this way :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();     
Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(New_Quote_Activity.this) + "events");
ContentResolver cr1 = getContentResolver();

// event insert
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("calendar_id", 1);
values.put("title", "Text");
values.put("dtstart", cal.getTimeInMillis() + 1*60*1000); // event starts at 11 minutes from now
values.put("dtend", cal.getTimeInMillis()+5760*60*1000); // ends 60 minutes from now
values.put("description", edt_Location.getText().toString());
// values.put("visibility", 0);
values.put("hasAlarm", 1);
values.put("eventTimezone", Time.getCurrentTimezone());
Uri event = cr1.insert(EVENTS_URI, values);

// reminder insert
Uri REMINDERS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(New_Quote_Activity.this) + "reminders");
values = new ContentValues();
values.put( "event_id", Long.parseLong(event.getLastPathSegment()));
values.put( "method", 1 );
values.put( "minutes", 2880 );
cr1.insert( REMINDERS_URI, values );
```

For reading event use this code :

```
Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://calendar/events"), new String[]{ "calendar_id", "title", "description", "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation" }, null, null, null);         
    //Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars"), new String[]{ "_id", "name" }, null, null, null);
    String add = null;
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String[] CalNames = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    int[] CalIds = new int[cursor.getCount()];
    for (int i = 0; i < CalNames.length; i++) {
        CalIds[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
        CalNames[i] = "Event"+cursor.getInt(0)+": \nTitle: "+ cursor.getString(1)+"\nDescription: "+cursor.getString(2)+"\nStart Date: "+new Date(cursor.getLong(3))+"\nEnd Date : "+new Date(cursor.getLong(4))+"\nLocation : "+cursor.getString(5);
        if(add == null)
            add = CalNames[i];
        else{
            add += CalNames[i];
        }           
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.calendars)).setText(add);

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
```

Also, don't forgot to add this permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
```

Comment: He's asking how to retrieve it and not how to insert it. Plus you should be using constants instead of hardcoded strings

Comment: you can do by putting this code in function and passion the value you want to insert in events.